# PayPal - Purchases without "Buy Now" buttons

Tags: paypal

I am trying to support special sales of my items on my website to certain users (such as 50% off) but I cannot do this with the traditional "Buy Now" buttons as users could just copy and paste the url of that offer and everyone would get the special sale instead of select users.

Are there ways to sell through PayPal without using their buttons that could support "one time" offers to a single user so that the special sales would not be abused?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: There are numerous ways to handle something like this.  You really haven't provided enough info here to help you.  Are you working with PHP?  Are you using WordPress, by chance?

Comment: I am using PHP. I have implemented the IPN callback php script.

Comment: What you would need to do is build some sort of a shopping cart system, even if it's very basic and only handles a single product.  You could then provide coupon codes for the discounts and anything else you want to add.  Depending on what exactly you're working in there may be existing shopping carts that you can just load and utilize easily with PayPal already integrated.  For example, WordPress + WooCommerce + PayPal for WooCommerce would get this done for you, and those are all free products.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am going to look into those :)